# Manually Firebase initialization not working for Firebase Analytics since January 9, 2024

Tags: android, firebase

I have been using the following manually initialization of Firebase for almost a year and it has been working for Crashlytics and Analytics.

Since January 9, 2024 Analytics has stopped working and the curious fact is that Crashlytics is still working with this Firebase manually initialization.

I have seen that the problem is here since when I use the automatic Firebase initialization it works perfect...

What I have:

In my root AndroidManifest.xml the following to disable automatic Provider merger :

```
    <application
<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
    tools:node="remove"
    />
    </application>
```

After this I have manually Firebase initialization:

In OnCreate() method:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
    .setApiKey("your_api_key")
    .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

Comment: Have to you tried to use `tools:node="replace"` instead of `tools:node="remove"`?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours I have seen that with the following line of code it is working:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

I don't know why but it seems that in a newer version it is set to false automatically

Comment: User is answering it's own question.